# Unable to access the variable sent in POST

Tags: node.js, json, post, request

I sent a POST in my function to my server side (NodeJS), with the variable 'name'. 'name' is a string. However, I am unable to use this variable that I sent in the server-side.

I tried using req, req.body and req.body.name to access the variable I sent through POST. req gave me IncomingMessage {..}, req.body gave me {}, and req.body.name gave me undefined.

------Client Side------

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/addvoted", true);
request.send(name);
```

------Server Side------

```
app.post('/addvoted', function (req, res) {
    var postBody = req.body;
    console.log(postBody);
}
```

I expect the value of the variable name, which is a string, to be accessed in my server-side program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this function send parameters via url,
try this code

```
req.query.name
```

replace name with variable name that you are sending

Answer (score 0):

use npm body-parser

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

// POST /login gets urlencoded bodies
app.post('/login', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.username)
}``

Thank you.
```